# Difference between the suffixes "-titude" and "-titute"

Tags: suffixes

I vaguely remember the suffix "-titude" is related to a state of a particular action, such as "certitude", which means a state of being sure. But I don't know what this kind of suffix actually is relevant to and how it differs from another suffix "-titute".

Comment: BTW, anyone interested in a reverse-alphabetized (i.e, sorted by ending first) word speculum can access [this text file (one word per line)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/speculum.txt). The command I used to generate it was $ `rev wordlist | sort | rev > speculum.txt`. It displays 140 contiguous English words ending -_ude_, ranging from _allude_ to _exude_, and 173 ending -_ute_, ranging from _saute_ to _astute_. Not all words fit the patterns, of course, but all the words that do are in the sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[-tude](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-TUde&searchmode=none) : is a common suffix used to form abstract nouns:

> - syllable formed when the word-forming element -ude, making abstract nouns from adjectives and participles, is fixed to a base or to another suffix ending in -t or -te; from French -ude, from Latin -udo (stem -udin-). The equivalent of native -ness. ([words ending with -tude](http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/tude/))

- *-tute or -ute* are not really suffixes with a specific connotation! ([words ending with -tute](http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/Tute))

Comment: _-ute_ generally comes from a Latin past participle, and so originally had adjectival meaning, still evident in _destitute_. But that's not very helpful now, because most of the words have become nouns or verbs, and in modern English have lost their former adjectival senses completely.