# History of '-itute' suffix?

Tags: suffixes

What is the history of the suffix -itute, as in constitute, prostitute, institute, restitute, and substitute?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231010/difference-between-the-suffixes-titude-and-titute. 

   
***-ute***  generally comes from a Latin past participle, and so originally had adjectival meaning, still evident in destitute. But that's not very helpful now, because most of the words have become nouns or verbs, and in modern English have lost their former adjectival senses completely. –  Colin Fine Feb 28 -2015.

Answer (score 9):

It's not so much a suffix, but is rather a root. It comes from the latin *statuere*, "cause to stand, establish" which comes from the Proto-Indoeuropean root *steh₂- "to stand."

As words change in meaning over the years and centuries, and have different origins from other languages even though they share the same root, it might not be immediately obvious how these words all share the same root. A good dictionary with etymology will shed light on this.

Here's a list of the words you gave and the prefix meanings used. I'll also give a rough translation with the root so you have an idea how the meanings evolved.

*Prostitute* uses the prefix *pro-* "before" and comes from the latin past participle of *prostituere*: "to expose publicly."
**Stand Before**

*Constitute* derives from the latin prefix *com-* "with, together"
**Establish Together**

*Institute* uses the prefix *in-* "into, in, on, upon."
**Establish Upon**

*Restitute* uses the prefix *re-* "again, back, anew."
**Establish Anew**

*Substitute* uses the prefix *sub-* "under, below, beneath, at the foot of."
**Stand in place of**

Another word with this root is:

*Destitute* using the prefix *de-* "away" which as taken the meaning "abandoned/forsaken" **Stand Away/Without**

Comment: Are you saying that the ending is in fact '-stitute' rather than 'itute'?

Comment: I'm saying that *statuere* is a root, not a suffix. The words given originally came from latin words that modified the root word with prefixes, which have taken new meanings.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. I would say that the prefixes are, con, pro, in, re, sub. This suggests that the ending we are discussing should not be '-itute' as suggested in the title and in the question but should instead be '-stitute'.

Comment: I agree. I suppose one could to correct the question, or point out misconceptions in the question in the answer. I chose the second path. :)

Comment: ***Frenditute***: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2816

Comment: Minor niggle: the Indo-European root for ‘stand’ is normally reconstructed as _*steh₂-_, rather than _*sta-_. The presence of the laryngeal is evidenced, among other things, by the metathesis-aspiration in the derived instrument noun, _*steh₂-tlo-_ > _*ste-tʰlo-_ ‘a place where you stand things’, which gives Latin _stabulum_ ‘stable (for horses)’; if it had been a simple _*sta-_ in PIE, a stable would have been _†staculum_ in Latin, so we’d be putting our horses up in stackles (or something like that).

Comment: So are these words neologisms in English based on Latinate roots, or are they borrowed with minor modifications from Latin?

Comment: @Mitch Most of them were taken straight from Latin during the English Renaissance.

Comment: @ghoppe Then you should add that fact (and others) to this in order to answer the OPs question which was about the history of the ending in English.

Answer (score 1):

The root is Latin **Sta-** re to stand.
**stitu** -ere is a iterative /frequentative form of the word. (thanks Janus Bahs Jacquet)

In the same way, **repetitive** is a reiterative form of **repeto** meaning to seek again and again.

**-stitutio** is the abstract noun form which gives us **-stitution;** and **stitute** is an English /possibly French back-formation to give the verb form. This verb form is used as a noun in the way that many verbs become nouns.

What the words have in common is that they are established by long practice.

Comment: What you call _reiterative_ is—to my knowledge, at least—usually called simply the _iterative_ (or sometimes _frequentative_). Are you using _reiterative_ deliberately here?