# Altitude, longitude, latitude, and probably multitude

Tags: etymology, morphology

It seems that **latitude**, **longitude**, and **altitude** should be composed of two constituents, since they all describe a geographical attribute, and all end with "tude".

However searching their etymology in Google does'nt give information about **tude** part.

So, what is **tude** in forming a word (morphology)?
Also is **multitude** is made of something similar?

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/231010/2085

Comment: If you want to know about the structure of words, use a dictionary. There are plenty of reputable on-line dictionaries (Oxford, Cambridge, Merriem-Webster).

Answer (score 2):

The English *-itude* morpheme is not originally an English suffix. It’s a Latin one by way of French. That means you’re asking about Latin here, not English.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tudo#Latin):

> ## -*tūdō* f (genitive -*tūdinis*); third declension
>
> used to form abstract nouns indicating a state or condition.
>
> The suffix -*tūdō* is added to an adjective to form an abstract third declension feminine noun indicating a state or condition.
>
> #### Examples:
>
> - *magnitūdō* (“greatness”), from *magnus* (“great”)
> - *mollitūdō* (“softness”), from *mollis* (“soft”)

There are a multitude these that have come down to English. The OED mentions these amongst others:

> abatude, acerbitude, acritude, adaptitude, aegritude, aletude, 
>   altilatitude, altitude, amaritude, ambitude, amplitude, anxietude, 
>   aptitude, arctitude, aritude, assuetude, attitude, beatitude, beautitude, 
>   bellitude, blanditude, canitude, celestitude, celsitude, certitude, 
>   claritude, consimilitude, consuetitude, consuetude, correctitude, 
>   crassitude, crebritude, crispitude, debilitude, decrepitude, definitude, 
>   delassitude, desuetude, directitude, disertitude, dispiritude, 
>   disquietude, dissimilitude, dissuetude, diversitude, dulcitude, 
>   exactitude, excelsitude, faustitude, femininitude, fessitude, finitude, 
>   firmitude, fomblitude, fortitude, gratitude, habitude, hebetude, hesitude, 
>   humilitude, implanitude, impromptitude, inaptitude, incertitude, 
>   incorrectitude, indefinitude, ineptitude, inertitude, inexactitude, 
>   infinitude, infortitude, ingratitude, inquietude, insuetude, invaletude, 
>   inverisimilitude, juventude, largitude, lassitude, latitude, laxitude, 
>   lenitude, lentitude, libitude, limpitude, lippitude, longitude, 
>   macritude, magnitude, mansuetude, mollitude, multitude, necessitude, 
>   Negritude, nigritude, oblongitude, omnitude, orbitude, parvitude, 
>   penitude, pinguitude, planitude, platitude, plenitude, plentitude, 
>   plumptitude, profunditude, promptitude, propensitude, pulchritude, 
>   putritude, quietude, rectitude, resolicitude, rubetude, salsitude, 
>   sanctitude, sanitude, segnitude, senectitude, senectude, serenitude, 
>   servitude, siccitude, similitude, solicitude, solitude, sorditude, 
>   spissitude, suavitude, tabitude, tarditude, temeritude, teneritude, 
>   torpitude, turpitude, unaptitude, uncertitude, ungratitude, unitude, 
>   unquietude, valetude, vastitude, verisimilitude, vicissitude.

All of those are abstract nouns for the state or condition of the baseline Latin adjective they’re each originally derived from in Latin.

Some of those are familiar or at least recognizable to all speakers of English; others perhaps only to the more (classically) educated ones. Back when to be educated meant to know Latin, writers would borrow these straight from Latin right into English without a second thought. These days, some have fallen into desuetude.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the etymology of each of the words you mentioned, according to Oxford Living Dictionary:

> *latitude* late Middle English: from Latin latitudo ‘breadth,’ from latus ‘broad.’
>
> *longitude* late Middle English (also denoting length and tallness): from Latin longitudo, from longus ‘long.’
>
> *altitude* late Middle English: from Latin altitudo, from altus ‘high.’
>
> *multitude* Middle English: via Old French from Latin multitudo, from multus ‘many.’

So, it's ultimately a question about Latin. Here's what [this Wikitionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-tudo) has to say about the *tudo* suffix in Latin:

> The suffix -tūdō is added to an adjective to form an abstract third declension feminine noun indicating a state or condition.

Comment: Didn't I say just that? :)